# Executing a stored procedure within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I would like to execute a stored procedure within a stored procedure, e.g.

```
EXEC SP1

BEGIN

EXEC SP2
END
```

But I only want `SP1` to finish after `SP2` has finished running so I need to find a way for `SP1` to wait for `SP2` to finish before `SP1` ends.

`SP2` is being executed as part of `SP1` so I have something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN

EXECUTE SP2

END
```

Comment: tags tweaked - "server" caused some false positives

Comment: Hi, retagged.  We're rationalising the mssql and sqlserver tags.

Comment: Looks like this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170440/stored-procedure-not-being-executed-within-another-stored-procedure). Please only ask your question once.

Answer (score 44):

T-SQL is not asynchronous, so you really have no choice but to wait until SP2 ends. Luckily, that's what you want.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP1 AS
   EXEC SP2
   PRINT 'Done'
```

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example of one of our stored procedures that executes multiple stored procedures within it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AssetLibrary_AssetDelete]
(
    @AssetID AS uniqueidentifier
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

EXEC AssetLibrary_AssetDeleteAttributes @AssetID
EXEC AssetLibrary_AssetDeleteComponents @AssetID
EXEC AssetLibrary_AssetDeleteAgreements @AssetID
EXEC AssetLibrary_AssetDeleteMaintenance @AssetID

DELETE FROM
    AssetLibrary_Asset
WHERE
    AssetLibrary_Asset.AssetID = @AssetID

RETURN (@@ERROR)
```

Answer (score 13):

Inline Stored procedure we using as per our need. 
Example like different Same parameter with different values we have to use in queries..

```
Create Proc SP1
(
 @ID int,
 @Name varchar(40)
 -- etc parameter list, If you don't have any parameter then no need to pass.
 )

  AS
  BEGIN

  -- Here we have some opereations

 -- If there is any Error Before Executing SP2 then SP will stop executing.

  Exec SP2 @ID,@Name,@SomeID OUTPUT 

 -- ,etc some other parameter also we can use OutPut parameters like 

 -- @SomeID is useful for some other operations for condition checking insertion etc.

 -- If you have any Error in you SP2 then also it will stop executing.

 -- If you want to do any other operation after executing SP2 that we can do here.

END
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats how it works stored procedures run in order, you don't need begin just something like

```
exec dbo.sp1
exec dbo.sp2
```

Comment: You could also wrap it in a transaction just too make sure it all executes correctly.