# Stored procedure not being executed within another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have found that SP2 doesn't execute from within SP1 when SP1 is executed.

Below is the structure of SP1:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP1 AS BEGIN

Declare c1 cursor....

open c1 fetch next from c1 ...

while @@fetch_status = 0 Begin

...

Fetch Next from c1 end

close c1

deallocate c1

exec sp2

end
```

---

I see non of the PRINT statement outputs if they are printed in the 'Output window' in SQL Server 2005 management studio as the 'Output Window'is empty.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the stored procedure? I'm wondering if it is **not** even getting to the exec sp2 line.

Comment: You might want to avoid Fetch Next. They are really not efficient and impact performance a lot.

Comment: thanks can you suggest an alternative way without using fetch next?

Comment: Look here: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=060113

Comment: Are you running the stored procedure from the command line, or from within an application? If you're executing it from within an application, make sure your connection isn't being closed before sp2 executes.

Answer (score 3):

What happens if you run the Stored Procedure code as a single query? If you put a `PRINT` statement before and after the exec, do you see both outputs?

- If you do, then the stored procedure must have been executed. Probably it's not doing what you would like.
- If you don't see any print output, then there's something wrong in the cycle
- If you don't see the second output but you see the first, there's something wrong in the second Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it helps you, but from my experience the most popular reasons are:

1. `sp2` gets some parameter which makes it `null` value -- i.e. you build its name from the strings and one of them is `null`.
2. `sp2` has some conditions inside and none of them is true, so `sp2` executes no code at all -- i.e. one of the parameters is type `varchar`, you pass value `VALUE`, check for it inside, but the real value passed to `sp2` is `V` (because there are no varchar length defined).
3. `sp2` builds query from parameters where one of them is `null` and the whole query becomes `null` too.

Do you see any output if you put `PRINT` *before* and *after* call of `sp2`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use @@error to see if there was an error when executing the previous statement.