# How to execute stored procedure in another stored procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on sql server 2008.

And i have a stored procedure in which i am executing one more usp.

Here i want to get the output of second usp and return the main usp output parameter accordingly.

But my main usp always returning the second usp value with the main usp value.

But i want to return only main usp value.

Below is my procedure :

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[usp_ChangeStatus](@id int,@Status int,@Name varchar(300),@Success int output  )
as
set @Success=0
begin try   

if exists(Select * from tbl_abc where id= @id)
Begin               

    if(@Status =1)
    begin
        ----Try-Catch block----
        begin try               
            declare @AddHostStatus as int
            set @AddHostStatus=0                
                            exec @AddHostStatus =usp_xyz @Name,0,@Address       
            if(@AddHostStatus=-3)               
            begin
            set @Success=1
            end             
        end try
        begin catch
            set @Success=0
        end catch
        ----End-Try-Catch block----     
    end     
    if(@Success=1)
    begin               
    --do something here         
    end                 
 End 
        end try 
        begin catch 
    set @Success=0  
     end catch
        select  @Success
```

Comment: Stored the output of Sp you are executing in a variable. I think that would do the trick.

Comment: please show code for "usp_Insert_Update_Details"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing a stored procedure within a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170328/executing-a-stored-procedure-within-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 25):

Try this

Suppose you have one stored procedure like this

**First stored procedure:**

```
Create  PROCEDURE LoginId
     @UserName nvarchar(200),
     @Password nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @loginID  int

    SELECT @loginID = LoginId 
    FROM UserLogin 
    WHERE UserName = @UserName AND Password = @Password

    return @loginID
END
```

Now you want to call this procedure from another stored procedure like as below

**Second stored procedure**

```
Create  PROCEDURE Emprecord
         @UserName nvarchar(200),
         @Password nvarchar(200),
         @Email nvarchar(200),
         @IsAdmin bit,
         @EmpName nvarchar(200),
         @EmpLastName nvarchar(200),
         @EmpAddress nvarchar(200),
         @EmpContactNo nvarchar(150),
         @EmpCompanyName nvarchar(200)

    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO UserLogin VALUES(@UserName,@Password,@Email,@IsAdmin)

        DECLARE @EmpLoginid int

        exec @EmpLoginid= LoginId @UserName,@Password

        INSERT INTO tblEmployee VALUES(@EmpName,@EmpLastName,@EmpAddress,@EmpContactNo,@EmpCompanyName,@EmpLoginid)
    END
```

As you seen above, we can call one stored procedure from another

Comment: Please what if the `exec @EmpLoginid= LoginId @UserName,@Password` has out parameter ?