# IF statement using output of SPROC SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, stored-procedures

I am creating stored procedures (sprocs) to perform operations on my tables in my database. I have a sproc `SubjectExists` that returns '1' if the subject name entered is in the subject table and returns '0' if it does not exist.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SubjectExists @SubjName varhcar(20)
AS
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM Subject 
WHERE Subject_Name = @SubjName
)
THEN CAST (1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT)
END
```

I am now making another sproc that deletes a subject from the table. I want to make this sproc such that it uses `SubjectExists` and if the output of it is a 1 (i.e. the subject does exist) then it deletes the subject and if the output from `SubjectExists` is 0, it does nothing.

How would I go about doing this?

I have tried experimenting with the below but no luck so far.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteSubject @SubjName varchar(20)
AS
IF (EXEC StudentExists Bob)
DELETE FROM Subject 
WHERE Subject_Name = @SubjName;
```

Can anyone please guide me as to how I would do this.
Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: I recommend you don't. T-SQL's facilities for modularity are very limited. Trying to apply "best practices" as featured in other languages is going to lead to hardship. Packing this code up as an inline table-valued function (not a multi-statement one!) is as close as you'll get to a decent solution, but that will still be inferior to expanding the condition in your original procedure. (For a complete story, see [this](http://sommarskog.se/share_data.html).)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211107/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-another-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: Why write such code at all? Just execute the `DELETE` as is. What you try to do would execute the exact same query twice

Comment: You can simply perform the `delete` and use `@@RowCount` to determine if anything was actually deleted. That avoids a _race condition_ that arises if the data changes between operations. If have other reasons to check for an existing row you could create a scalar user-defined function that returns a `Bit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, your stored procedure should return value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SubjectExists @SubjName varchar(20)
AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue int

    SELECT @ReturnValue = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM Subject 
        WHERE Subject_Name = @SubjName
        )
        THEN CAST (1 AS BIT)
        ELSE CAST (0 AS BIT)
        END

    RETURN @ReturnValue
    END
```

Then you can declare some table to store results of your stored procedure and if it is eligible, then run your code

```
DECLARE @FooValue int;
EXEC  @FooValue = SubjectExists 'helloWorld!:)' 

IF  @FooValue = 1
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM Subject 
        WHERE Subject_Name = @SubjName;
    END
```

Comment: In the Subject Exists SPROC, the return statement (2nd last line) you've put causes a syntax error

Comment: How does `@ReturnValue` work without ever having a value assigned?

Comment: @HABO ooops, thanks for your attention. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @StepUp `RETURN @ReturnValue` is problematic. syntax error shows when I put it in

Comment: @Sam please, see my updated answer.

Comment: Aside: You could factor out the `cast`, e.g. `cast ( case ... end as bit )`, but since both `@ReturnValue` and `return` deal in `int` there's no point in either factoring or casting.

Comment: @StepUp, would the second piece of code then be the SPROC for DeleteSubject? I've used it as that. when I execute `DeleteSubject` on a subject that doesn't exist, it shows 0 rows affected but also does the same for a subject that does exist

Comment: @Sam please, see my updated answer. Now, I properly tested my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the return value from the stored procedure like this-

```
DECLARE @returnvalue INT

 EXEC @returnvalue = StudentExists Bob
```

and then you can make your `If` condition.

Comment: Except his first stored procedure doesn't have a return value.

Comment: i have tried this but still doesn't work, just returns 0/1 based on SubjectExists.                                                                                     CREATE PROC                                                                                                  
AS                                                                                                          DECLARE 'Exists int
exec 'Exists = StudentExists 'StudName
IF(@Exists= 1)
DELETE FROM Student 
WHERE Student_Name = StudName
ELSE
PRINT NULL;   //doesnt let me put the at symbol in so ive put ' instead