# Insert results from Stored Procedures in a Temp Table with additional data

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am working with a stored procedure that uses the output from existing procedures to process a formula and compute a result. I am using a temporary table to store the results from the external procedures for use in the formula, but am having a hard time getting it to work the way I want.

I do not have the ability to alter the existing procedures that I am working with.

Here is a simplified example of what I would like to achieve:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GET_CUBIC_VOLUME,

@MYITEM varchar(25) = null,
@MY_RESULT decimal(38,2) OUTPUT

AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @MY_HEIGHT decimal(38,2)
DECLARE @MY_WIDTH decimal(38,2)
DECLARE @MY_DEPTH decimal(38,2)

CREATE TABLE #MYVARS (V_NAME varchar(max),V_VAL money)

INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('HEIGHT', EXEC GET_ITEM_HEIGHT @MYITEM)
INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('WIDTH', EXEC GET_ITEM_WIDTH @MYITEM)
INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('DEPTH', EXEC GET_ITEM_DEPTH @MYITEM)

SET @MY_HEIGHT = (SELECT V_VAL from #MYVARS where V_NAME='HEIGHT')
SET @MY_WIDTH = (SELECT V_VAL from #MYVARS where V_NAME='WIDTH')
SET @MY_DEPTH = (SELECT V_VAL from #MYVARS where V_NAME='DEPTH')

SET @MY_RESULT = @MY_HEIGHT * @MY_WIDTH * @MY_DEPTH
SELECT @MY_RESULT

RETURN
```

The issue I'm having is doing the insert to the temp table with a string to say what it is, along with the result from the appropriate stored procedure.

Any insight on how to achieve this without changing the existing procedures, or having to create a temp table for each variable, would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (That doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Whats the error?  Is anything/nothing being inserted into #MYVARS?

Comment: @tshoemake

The error is "incorrect syntax near ____" with the blank being 'Height' or whatever I am trying to put in the table. When I omit the string for V_NAME, it will leave that field null and record the output of the secondary procedure for V_VAL. I just can't figure out how to get both to work together.

Answer (score 0):

After you declare your variables..

```
set @MY_HEIGHT = EXEC GET_ITEM_HEIGHT @MYITEM
set @MY_WIDTH = EXEC GET_ITEM_WIDTH @MYITEM
set @MY_DEPTH = EXEC GET_ITEM_DEPTH @MYITEM
```

Then change inserts to..

```
INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('HEIGHT', @MY_HEIGHT)
INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('WIDTH', @MY_WIDTH)
INSERT INTO #MYVARS (V_NAME,V_VAL) values ('DEPTH', @MY_DEPTH)
```

Not sure youll even need to insert into a myvars temp now though.

Comment: This kind of works, except that the query only returns the first set variable when executed.

So if I do 

         EXEC MY_HEIGHT = GET_ITEM_HEIGHT MYITEM

No matter what else I do in the procedure, when I execute it from a query, the output will be whatever MY_HEIGHT is.

Comment: Are you using sql server management studio?  Here's another example of the multiple execs working in a sproc: http://stackoverflow.com/a/170359/2803703 Also are you receiving an error?

Comment: I really appreciate your input. Thank you for that.

I don't know why I am having this issue, but when I attempt to set the variables as you noted, I only get the first set value back when I execute the procedure from a query.

I even explicitly added "Select thisvar, thatvar, thatothervar" at the end of the procedure and it still only spits out the first set variable.

Comment: I need to see the contents of your GET_ITEM_HEIGHT sproc.  Paste this into your OP.